# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process.

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The app works fine with minSdkVersion 24 but upon reducing it to minSdkVersion 19 I am getting few errors. On running it in my device but there is no error upon gradle sync.The error log is posted. The dependencies work well with minSdkVersion 24, but not in minSdkVersion 19 , getting me the below listed errors and I need it to work on the lower version like minSdkVersion 19. Any help would be appreciated.

ERROR LOG HERE:
4 errors ,1 warning

```
Calculate task graph    122ms
Run tasks   2m 7s 746ms null    
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.  
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\common-java8\1.1.1\795d68cd761d093ccb235d1d91b8fd17c2ae25ff\common-java8-1.1.1.jar   
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.  
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException   
null    
Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void android.arch.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver.onCreate(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)
```

My app level gradle file.(minSdkversion 24 here)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.mkchat"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1-beta1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
// alternatively - just ViewModel
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1" // use -ktx for Kotlin
// alternatively - just LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1"
// alternatively - Lifecycles only (no ViewModel or LiveData).
//     Support library depends on this lightweight import
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
// alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of compiler
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"
// optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1"
// optional - Test helpers for LiveData
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 18):

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate a little about the proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your source compatibility & target compatibility is not Java-8. Set that to Java-8.

Answer (score 0):

Removing these lines from the gradle helped remove the errors and run successfully on my phone for making it run in below android version 7

```
 // alternatively - just ViewModel
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1" // use -ktx for Kotlin
// alternatively - just LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1"
// alternatively - Lifecycles only (no ViewModel or LiveData).
//     Support library depends on this lightweight import
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
// alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of compiler
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"
// optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1"
// optional - Test helpers for LiveData
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

i can't fix it by all the answer above, but i figured out the solution. I remove library appcompat v4 from my libs project folder.

> yourprojectfolder > app > libs > appcompat...rar

delete that and restart your android studio.